# MySQL PHP Syntax Error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I cannot figure out where the syntax error is in this line of code.

```
$cuQ = mysql_query("SELECT aQID 
                      FROM approvedQuestions 
                     WHERE staus = '1'");
```

Comment: Is the column really named `staus`?

Comment: What is the actual error message?  Because MySQL will tell you if it's a matter of syntax vs a non-existent column (due to typo?)

Comment: You should always write the error message/output where possible. Saying just 'I have some errors' is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Non-existent column

You wrote `staus`, but was this meant to say `status`? If so, then you have written a token that is not a field name, and MySQL doesn't know what to make of it.

### BTW...

I recommend using *backticks* (`` ` ``) to delimit field names.

This resolves ambiguities in your SQL statements; were one of them a reserved name ([none are](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)) then in fact you'd *have* to do this:

```
SELECT `aQID`
  FROM `approvedQuestions`
 WHERE `status` = '1';
```

Comment: I think you figured it out. It should be "status" instead of "staus" Thanks :)

Comment: Wasn't me that downvoted, but I don't recommend using backticks for everything -- rather the opposite, so you learn MySQL reserved words and not to use them unless absolutely necessary.  Backticks don't exist to be relied upon as a crutch.

Comment: @OMGPonies: I am not recommending the use of them as a crutch; I am recommending the use of them because that's what's proper. If you need a practical reason, it makes code syntax highlighting more effective. If you want to learn MySQL reserved words, do it by [reading the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) rather than by messing up your queries.

Comment: There's nothing proper about using backticks for *every possibility* -- that is, by definition & general consensus, a crutch.  Knowing why, and fixing the issue when an error occurs is "proper" -- not hiding from the issue.

Comment: @OMGPonies: The formal syntax includes them. That you are allowed to omit them in unambiguous cases is not relevant!

Comment: Another downvote on the answer that the OP has already said solved the problem. This isn't `meta`, guys; downvotes are for not disagreeing with a recommendation, but for marking unhelpful, dangerous and incorrect assertions.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$cuQ = mysql_query("SELECT aQID FROM approvedQuestions WHERE `status`='1'");
```

Comment: you may wanna put tick marks around the `\`status\`` too, I think its a reserved word.

Comment: MySQL has different errors for syntax & non-existent columns, so I'm inclined to say this is not the answer until the OP clarifies.

Comment: `status` is _not_ a reserved word, and [it was really easy to find that out](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html).

Comment: it would be nice if PDO had a ->quote_identifier like Perls DBI does.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$cuQ = mysql_query("SELECT `aQID` FROM `approvedQuestions` WHERE `status`= 1");
```

You should always cover your table names and fields wiht backtick (`) symbol in order to insure that MySQL queries run properly in situations where names conflict with SQL keywords.

Comment: Yes but would you like to explain _why_, for the OP's benefit? Answers that just say "try this" are harmful. :(

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, newlines in strings should be avoided. Different operating systems (Windows vs. UNIX-like) handle them differently, so they're not portable. If you want to keep your queries neat, I recommend using `sprintf`, like so:

```
$cuQ = sprintf(
    'SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE %s = %d',
    'aQID',
    'approvedQuestions',
    'staus',
    1
);
```

This formatting lends itself nicely to using variables instead of hard-coded values. You can always use `\r` (carriage return) and `\n` (newline) inline in your double-quoted strings if you need to have newlines in your strings;

Comment: @Rattner Formatting is made by *OMG Ponies*

Comment: Why should newlines in strings be avoided? And how does this answer the question?

Comment: I don't think so, outside of a literal string newlines can be used withut any problem.

Comment: If anything I'd say that this approach is actually **harmful**, because it _looks like_ PDO is being used when it is not.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: "Looking like when it's not" isn't harmful -- `sprintf` is less preferable than PDO but still better than SQL as a string because `sprintf` prompts proper data type handling.  If you're going to tear into something, do yourself a favour -- make sure your justification is legitimate.

Comment: @OMGPonies: If you disagree with me then that is fine, but my justification is no less legitimate for it; a programmer may conceivably alter the query unsafely if in a hurry, on the assumption that the parameters are being inserted in some intelligent fashion (rather than just through string insertion), because the prepared statements pattern looks just like this. I don't appreciate your attitude.